# Problems with return value by "WHERE" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine we had 2 tables and I wanna return all columns from table1 with one column from table2 than I use where to filter table2's column

look at this query :

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.name AS anotherName 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE anotherName LIKE '%something here %'
```

I know I can't use anotherName Like this and I got Error but I don't have any idea to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias is detected in `having` clause but not in `where` clause. If you insist on using the alias in the condition, you need to use `having` instead if `where`:

```
HAVING anotherName LIKE '%something here %'
```

Otherwise you must call the original name:

```
WHERE t2.name LIKE '%something here %'
```

You can also check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) link to see why alias cannot be used in a `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

try like below just use directly that column in where

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.name AS anotherName 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE t2.name LIKE '%something here %'
```